# Double DQN performs significantly worse than vanilla DQN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I have an agent that has to explore a customized environment.

The environment is a grid (100 squares horizontally, 100 squares vertically, each square is 10 meters wide).

In the environment, there are a number of users (called ues) whose positions are randomized at the beginning of each episode and are stationary throughout the episode.

Each user requires a number of resources that varies depending on the agent's position (the nearer the agent gets to a user, the fewer resources it will require and the more satisfied it will be | the satisfaction of a user is measured by how many resources it was given, if it was given all the resources it needs, then it will be satisfied), so the agent has to find the position that satisfies the maximum number of users (the agent is not aware of the users' positions).

The state space contains the agent's current position, the number of satisfied users, and a list of requests (What type of resources each user is asking for)

The action space is comprised of 9 actions (move forward, backward, to the sides, stay still, etc)

The agent's position is randomized at the beginning of each episode.

Epsilon is decayed from 1 to 0.1 over 550 episodes.

The reward function is as follows:

- If the agent chose an action that takes it to a position that satisfies more users than the previous position or the agent chose an action that takes it to a position that satisfies the same number of users as the previous position and there hasn't been a previous position where the agent satisfied more users than the current position, then the reward would be of value 2.
- If the agent chose an action that takes it to a position that satisfies the same number of users as the previous position and there has been a previous position where the agent satisfied more users than the current position then the penalty would be -0.001.
- If the agent chose an action that takes it to a position that satisfies a fewer number of users than the previous position then the penalty would be -0.002.

I use soft updates to the target network in my code with `tau=1e-3`

My problem is that Double DQN seems to perform much worse than vanilla DQN and I do not know why. It's supposed to perform better, right? Is there something wrong with the reward function maybe? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Here's what the average reward curve looks like so far:

[image]

Here's my code for Double DQN below:

```
DISCOUNT = 0.9 #0.99
REPLAY_MEMORY_SIZE = 10_000  
MIN_REPLAY_MEMORY_SIZE = 10_000  # Minimum number of steps in a memory to start training
MINIBATCH_SIZE = 32 # How many steps (samples) to use for training
class DDQNAgent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #self.gamma = 0.95 
        self.epsilon = 1.0
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.8
        self.epsilon_min = 0.1
        self.learning_rate = 10e-4 #0.0005 #0.25 #1e-4
        self.tau = 1e-3
        
        self.plot_loss_acc = PlotLearning()
                
        # Main models
        self.model_uav_pos = self._build_pos_model()

        # Target networks
        self.target_model_uav_pos = self._build_pos_model()
        # Copy weights
        self.target_model_uav_pos.set_weights(self.model_uav_pos.get_weights())

        # An array with last n steps for training
        self.replay_memory_pos_nn = deque(maxlen=REPLAY_MEMORY_SIZE)

        tboard_log_dir_pos = os.path.join("logs", MODEL_NAME_POS_DDQN)
        self.tensorboard_pos = ModifiedTensorBoard(MODEL_NAME_POS_DDQN, log_dir=tboard_log_dir_pos)
        
    def _build_pos_model(self): # compile the DNN
        # create the DNN model
        dnn = self.create_pos_dnn()
        
        opt = Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate) #, decay=self.epsilon_decay)
        dnn.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
        dnn.call = tf.function(dnn.call, jit_compile=True)
        
        return dnn
    
    ''' Don't forget to normalize the inputs '''
    def create_pos_dnn(self): 
        # initialize the input shape (The shape of an array is the number of elements in each dimension)
        pos_input_shape = (2,)
        requests_input_shape = (len(env.ues),)
        number_of_satisfied_ues_input_shape = (1,)
        # How many possible outputs we can have
        output_nodes = n_possible_movements
        
        # Initialize the inputs
        uav_current_position = Input(shape=pos_input_shape, name='pos')
        ues_requests = Input(shape=requests_input_shape, name='requests')
        number_of_satisfied_ues = Input(shape=number_of_satisfied_ues_input_shape, name='number_of_satisfied_ues')
        
        # Put them in a list
        list_inputs = [uav_current_position, ues_requests, number_of_satisfied_ues]
        
        # Merge all input features into a single large vector
        x = layers.concatenate(list_inputs)
        
        # Add a 1st Hidden (Dense) Layer
        dense_layer_1 = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
        
        # Add a 2nd Hidden (Dense) Layer
        dense_layer_2 = Dense(512, activation="relu")(dense_layer_1)
        
        # Add a 3rd Hidden (Dense) Layer
        dense_layer_3 = Dense(256, activation="relu")(dense_layer_2)
        
        # Output layer
        output_layer = Dense(output_nodes, activation="softmax")(dense_layer_3)

        model = Model(inputs=list_inputs, outputs=output_layer)
                        
        # return the DNN
        return model
    
    def remember_pos_nn(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.replay_memory_pos_nn.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done)) # list of previous experiences, enabling re-training later
        
    def act_upon_choosing_a_new_position(self, state): # state is a tuple (uav_position, requests_array)
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon: # if acting randomly, take random action
            return random.randrange(n_possible_movements)
        pos =  np.array([state[0]])
        reqs =  np.array([state[1]])
        number_satisfaction = np.array([state[2]])
        act_values = self.model_uav_pos([pos, reqs, number_satisfaction]) # if not acting randomly, predict reward value based on current state
        return np.argmax(act_values[0]) #env.possible_positions[np.argmax(act_values[0])] # pick the action that will give the highest reward
        
    def train_pos_nn(self):
        print("In Training..")

        # Start training only if certain number of samples is already saved
        if len(self.replay_memory_pos_nn) < MIN_REPLAY_MEMORY_SIZE:
            print("Exiting Training: Replay Memory Not Full Enough...")
            return

        # Get a minibatch of random samples from memory replay table
        list_memory = list(self.replay_memory_pos_nn)
        random.shuffle(list_memory)
        minibatch = random.sample(list_memory, MINIBATCH_SIZE)

        start_time = time.time()
        # Enumerate our batches
        for index, (current_state, action, reward, new_current_state, done) in enumerate(minibatch):
            print('...Starting Training...')
            target = 0
            pos =  np.array([current_state[0]])
            reqs =  np.array([current_state[1]])
            number_satisfaction = np.array([current_state[2]])
            pos_next = np.array([new_current_state[0]])
            reqs_next = np.array([new_current_state[1]])
            number_satisfaction_next = np.array([new_current_state[2]])

            # If not a terminal state, get new q from future states, otherwise set it to 0
            # almost like with Q Learning, but we use just part of equation here
            if not done:
                max_action = np.argmax(self.model_uav_pos([pos_next, reqs_next, number_satisfaction_next])[0])
                target = reward + DISCOUNT * self.target_model_uav_pos([pos_next, reqs_next, number_satisfaction_next])[0][max_action]
            else:
                target = reward

            # Update Q value for a given state
            target_f = self.model_uav_pos([pos, reqs, number_satisfaction])
            target_f = np.array(target_f)
            target_f[0][action] = target

            self.model_uav_pos.fit([pos, reqs, number_satisfaction], \
                                   target_f, \
                                   verbose=2, \
                                   shuffle=False, \
                                   callbacks=None, \
                                   epochs=1 \
                                  )  
        end_time = time.time()
        print("Time", end_time - start_time)
        # Update target network counter every episode
        self.target_train() 

    def target_train(self):
        weights = self.model_uav_pos.get_weights()
        target_weights = self.target_model_uav_pos.get_weights()
        for i in range(len(target_weights)):
            target_weights[i] = weights[i] * self.tau + target_weights[i] * (1 - self.tau)
        self.target_model_uav_pos.set_weights(target_weights)
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, your output layer seems to have softmax activation. Is there a specific reason for that? DQN usually performs regression, since it must predict the value of an action at a state. Whereas the range of softmax is only between 0 and 1. 

I think I saw this in one of your earlier posts too.

Comment: I have 9 output neurons in the output layer representing the 9 actions (go forward, backward etc) and the agent has to predict which action to choose from those 9 outputs after the prediction is performed, and to my understanding it's akin to a classification problem and softmax activation function is to be used in this case. Am I wrong?

Comment: The DQNs that I am familiar with, predict the "value" of each action. For instance, if you n actions for a state, you'd have n output neurons. Each of those n output neurons predict the value of that corresponding action. After that, you'd typically select the action corresponding to the maximum neuron value. 
Disclaimer: That's how typical DQNs work. I am not sure if you modified your algorithm for your particular application.

Comment: According to my research I should use softmax activation function, but I'll look into it more. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: If you could provide some minimal working example, you'd get more responses from the SO community. 

What I'd do is, try running your code on a simple open-ai gym example (such as cartpole), to make sure your ddqn/dqn code is correct. Once you are sure of that, you could modify your code for your application.

Comment: That's some good advice! Thank you :)

Comment: There's this example that plays a snake game (the choice of actions is similar to my application) https://github.com/henniedeharder/snake/blob/master/agent_1.py and it uses softmax as an activation function for the output layer.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: I looked into the code and still believe that the use of softmax in the last layer is, at least, theoretically wrong. Please have a look here - https://www.quora.com/Why-does-DQN-use-a-linear-activation-function-in-the-final-layer-rather-than-more-common-functions-such-as-Relu-or-softmax and here - https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/34589/using-softmax-non-linear-vs-linear-activation-function-in-deep-reinforceme

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why your DDQN is performing worse than DQN. I could try listing a few here -

1. Deep Neural Networks are highly dependent on weight initialization. For a proper comparison between 2 algorithms, you'd want to place seeds so that the weight initialization is the same.
2. The same can be said about following an epsilon-greedy policy. Taking random actions, during random time-steps would lead you to obtain different rewards, which can affect future policies.
3. tau is a hyper-parameter that needs to be tuned. Depending on what value you use for tau, you could get different results from your DDQN.

I believe you can get much more assistance from the SO community if you add some working code, that can be tested out. For instance gym https://www.gymlibrary.ml/ has many standard and easy environments such as Cartpole that can be used for quick (<5 mins) code prototyping.